# Sending "Server Params" through Postman :

Tags: symfony, postman, symfony4, symfony-3.4

Thanks to **Symfony HttpFoundation component** , we can retrieve the **server params** like the following  script :

```
   // retrieves SERVER variables
    $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST')
```

So, i have the following construct and i'd like to have the server parameters :

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
$request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

$this->country = self::DEFAULT_COUNTRY;
$this->lang = self::DEFAULT_LANG;
$this->brand = self::DEFAULT_BRAND;
$this->jobBrand = $this->brand;

if ($request) {
    if (!empty($request->server->get(self::ENV_COUNTRY_CODE))) {
        $this->country = $request->server->get(self::ENV_COUNTRY_CODE);
    }

    if (!empty($request->server->get(self::ENV_LANG_CODE))) {
        $this->lang = $request->server->get(self::ENV_LANG_CODE);
    }

    if (!empty($request->server->get(self::ENV_BRAND))) {
        $this->jobBrand = $request->server->get(self::ENV_BRAND);
        $this->brand = str_replace('pro', '', $this->jobBrand);
    }

    if (empty($this->country) || empty($this->lang)) {
        throw new NoApacheLocaleException();
    }
}
}
```

For information, during the testing phase, I used **Postman** as an http client.

So my question is: how can I send my parameters via Postman in order to get it through  ***$request->server->get('param')*** ?

Comment: It depends if you request GET, POST, PUT verb.

Comment: @HéctorPrats I used the POST method

Comment: Short answer is: you can't.  $_SERVER is initialized by PHP based on server side information.  Does not use anything from the HTTP request.  I suppose you could fake it for testing by using variable names like _server_http_host and adjust your code accordingly.  But if you are using the Symfony framework then you might be better off using Symfony's functional testing approach.

Comment: @Cerad i think you are right.

Comment: @Cerad you can put the answer, i d liek to validate it and  it wil l be for everyone to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Cerad and I'm convinced by his answer :

***$_SERVER** is initialized by PHP based on server side information. Does not use anything from the HTTP request. I suppose you could fake it for testing by using variable names like **_server_http_host** and adjust your code accordingly. But if you are using the Symfony framework then you might be better off using Symfony's functional testing approach.*